# Secure, customizeable, open-source chat engine on PHP/JavaScript for all popular browsers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, chat

Please recommend Secure, customizeable, open-source chat on PHP/JavaScript for all popular browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrote my own chat.

Comment: is it secure, customizable, and open-source? if so, please share the link! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your are looking for something like [phpopenchat](http://www.phpopenchat.org/). It is secure, open-source, customizable and works an a PHP-basis for common browsers.

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function _no_tablespace() in ...chat\include\class.Installer.inc  on line 389" during the installation

Comment: It does not get further developed at this point.
I never had any installing problems - sry can't help you on that one.