# what's the best method to do chat function in php?

Tags: php, livechat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure, customizeable, open-source chat engine on PHP/JavaScript for all popular browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880988/secure-customizeable-open-source-chat-engine-on-php-javascript-for-all-popular)

Hi 
   I am about to do a chat function for a social networking site using php 
I want to gain inputs to do it .... Can any one suggest me which is the best method to do chat function in php

Comment: Numerous, numerous duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+chat

Answer (score 0):

You better reuse some existing PHP chat scripts like [PHPFreeChat](http://www.phpfreechat.net/).

But if you want to make your own then here is an idea .
You can setup own [IRCD](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=clO&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&&sa=X&ei=6WMTTM78FYL7lwe55YTmDA&ved=0CB0QBSgA&q=ircd+server&spell=1) on the server or use some other available IRC networks.Then build a chat interface with PHP ,can search google for available PHP irc clients you will find many (modify it to your needs ;) .